# What is the meaning behind the logo of Google Chrome?

Tags: logo, google

This is a question I have been asking myself for a while now. I found this question on [Quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-meaning-behind-the-Google-Chrome-icon-If-so-what-is-it), but honestly the answers are not really satisfactory in my opinion.

**The top answer uses this comparison:**

[image]

But I doubt the Chrome logo having any connection towards any of these except for the Google logo (especially the Pokéball...). The webcam maybe, but focusing a browser logo on a webcam would be pretty weird honestly.

**Another user compared the logo to the number 666, which might be fun, but it is also probably very wrong:**
[image]

**Here's the Chrome logo:**
[image]

I understand the logo consisting of the four different colors of the standard Google logo, but what exactly do the shapes represent? Is it just supposed to look dynamic or is there a deeper meaning laying underneath? Any ideas?

Comment: I think this can only be answered by the Google design team.

Comment: But maybe there are some resources on the design team commeting on this? Also I was asking for *ideas* aswell, not just "we made the logo and our thought process was this".

Comment: I think you're right, probably related to the 666 somehow.

Comment: -- Beachball of death --- symbolizing.. wait until we have **ALL** your personal data and use it against you. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest as a possible explanation of the logo:

- The colors represent the Google brand
- The blue ball represents the world (a la "world" wide web)
- The colored sections around the blue ball represent the variety and
  continual movement and exchange of information on the internet, as
  well as the constant crawling of the internet done by by Google in
  order to bring that information to their users.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought about the blue ball being the earth, but it makes sense. Way more than all the previous explanations I have seen.

Comment: @Maharkus that is because others are avoiding speculation since there's no official information on the actual meaning of the logo.

Comment: The quora question thread was full of wild speculation. In fact, what you just said would be a valid answer aswell. "What is the meaning of the logo?" "There is no official information on this, however here are a few possible ways it could be interpreted [...]"